# Perl XML::Smart Out of memory! error

Tags: mysql, xml, perl

I have this small Perl script that downloads an XML file, parses it using [`XML::Smart`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aSmart), and copies the contents into a MySQL database by deleting and recreating a table.

This script used to work fine on Centos 5, but recently the disk crashed, and the new drive has Centos 6 on it.

The XML file is 21.5MB in size.

I know it gets stuck at the point of parsing the file, as the database table is never deleted or created.

```
  my $XML = XML::Smart->new($location.'CategoriesList.xml')
      or die("Unable to parse CategoriesList.xml: $!");;
  $XML = $XML->cut_root();
  $XML = $XML->cut_root();

  $dbh->do("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ice_categories");
  $dbh->do("CREATE TABLE ice_categories (
      category_id int(11) not null,
      parent_cat_id int(11) not null,
      category_name varchar(100) not null default '',
      category_description varchar(100) not null default '',
      category_image varchar(100) not null default '',
      category_thumb varchar(100) not null default '',
      KEY (category_id), KEY (parent_cat_id))
      CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;");

  my @Categories = @{$XML->{CategoriesList}{Category}};

  my $c_categories = 0;
  foreach my $category (@Categories) {
    my $cat_name = ucwords($category->{Name}('langid','eq','1')->{Value});
    #print $category->{ID} . " => " . $cat_name . "\n";
    my $cat_desc = $category->{Description}('langid','eq','1')->{Value};
    my $cat_parent = $category->{ParentCategory}{ID};
    $dbh->do("INSERT ice_categories XXXX ");
    $c_categories++;
  }

  print "$c_categories categories imported.\n";
}
```

I am not very good at Perl, so any help would be appreciated. I have looked at [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig), but I'm not sure how to use it here.

Example of the xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE ICECAT-interface SYSTEM "http://data.icecat.biz/dtd/ICECAT-   
      interface_response.dtd">
   <ICECAT-interface>
   <Response Date="Sat Apr 26 14:46:53 2014" ID="13219513" Request_ID="1398516412" 
   Status="1">
        <CategoriesList>
        <Category ID="127" LowPic="http://images.icecat.biz/img/low_pic/127-563.jpg"   
        Score="9725" Searchable="0" ThumbPic="http://images.icecat.biz/thumbs/CAT127.jpg" 
         UNCATID="43171520" Visible="0">
         <Description ID="548838" Value="Device or stand where you can rest your mobile or 
        fixed telephone." langid="1"/>
        <Description ID="8310" Value="" langid="2"/>
        <Keywords ID="3274" Value="" langid="1"/>
        <Keywords ID="3275" Value="" langid="2"/>
        <Keywords ID="3276" Value="" langid="3"/>
        <Keywords ID="3277" Value="" langid="4"/>
        <Keywords ID="3278" Value="" langid="5"/>
        <Name ID="255" Value="telephone rests" langid="1"/>
        <Name ID="471173" Value="telefoon steunen" langid="2"/>
        <Name ID="343915" Value="autres téléphones" langid="3"/>
```

Comment: You have given us very little to go on. Can you show the contents of the XML or a link to it?

Comment: i have added snippet of the xml file

Comment: Here's a vote for using a constant-memory (e.g: SAX) parser instead of a DOM-based parser.

Answer (score 0):

One of the nice features of `XML::Twig` is that it supports `twig_handers` to 'deal with' XML as you're going, and it has the `purge` method, so you can chuck it away to keep memory footprint down.

I'm not familiar enough with `XML::Smart` to say 100% for sure, but it looks like you're simply processing `Category` elements as you go.

This *should* work, but with a partial XML sample (and thus not valid) I can't say entirely for sure.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

sub process_category {
    my ( $twig, $category ) = @_;
    my $cat_name = $category->get_xpath('./Name[@mode="source"]', 0)->text;

    my $cat_name = $category->get_xpath('./Name[@lang="1"]', 0)->text;
    my $cat_desc = $category->get_xpath('./Description[@lang="1"]', 0)->text;

    ### do something with cat_name and cat_desc

    my $cat_parent = $category -> first_child('ParentCategory') -> first_child_text('ID');
    $twig -> purge; #discard data thus far.
}

my $twig =
    XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 'Category' => \&process_category } );
$twig->parsefile('your_xml.xml');
```

I'm afraid I don't know where 'ParentCategory' comes from, so I haven't accounted for it. I'm *assuming* it's just an element in the XML you haven't shown, but it it's more complicated then `purge` might not be as helpful as is.